# how to avoid others connect to my port in XRPD

Tags: xrdp

I set a Remote connect to my ubuntu server via the XRPD.
I set the port to 5912.
But the users in my group can connect to the same port using his account and watching what I am doing. That is so terrible. 
Is there any idea to avoid this problem.
I try to read the config file in .xrdp.ini but find nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite unusual...When using xRDP, each user get a different session on the server....What you are describing would be the behavior of VNC software where a user can indeed connect to the same session (shadowing) and share the screen....

- Which version of Ubuntu are you running (lsb_release -a )
- Which version of xrdp are you running (check by typing xrdp -v)
- Are you starting a remote desktop client(Microsoft RDP - Remmina -
  xfreerdp) using the correct protocol (RDP and not vnc)
- How do you perform your remote connection ? (in the XRDP login page,
  are you selecting the option Xorg ?)

From a windows machine, the following process should happen

1. start your remote desktop client
2. type in ip address or hostname
3. the xRDP login screen should be displayed to you
4. do not change anything and provide your user name and password
5. if everything is ok, you should see your desktop loading and you can start working remotely

Hope this help

Til next time

See ya